# correcting for small sample sizes

Tags: mean, sample-size, small-sample

I have been toying with some data relating employment outcomes to choice of college major (which I got from a FiveThirtyEight Git repository). I have included a scatter plot where each point represents a college major, and the x and y axes represent the total number of students with that major and their average unemployment rate respectively. I'm noticing that there is a lot more variation in the majors with smaller numbers of students. Basically, I'm wondering whether that large amount of variation is just a result of having a large number of small sample sizes. Is there a way that I can correct for this?

E.g. If one data point shows a z-score of -2, but there are only 400 students with the corresponding major, how can I compare that to a z-score of -1 accounting for 40,000 students? Should I really believe the former has better employment prospects than the latter?

[image]

Comment: Well, the mean $\bar X_n$ of a sample of size $n$ from a population with SD $\sigma$ has $SD(\bar X_n) = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: Well, the actual $n$'s here are mostly very large --- If these are binomial data, the largest possible variance (when $p=1/2$) is $\fra1{4n}$. Probably there is some overdispersion, say with a factor of 100. If so, standard errors are bounded by $\sqrt{\frac{100}{4n}}=50/\sqrt{n}$. For $n=100000$ that is about 0.005

Comment: This is good to know, but I'm not sure that I understand the relevance to my question.